# Why can I access :number_to_currency but not :titleize as helpers in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think this is the default behaviour. I'm trying to use best_in_place with `:display_with => :titleize` to format the output.

How can I make sure `:titleize` is available in this namespace? Applying it to a symbols works, e.g. `@name.titleize`, but not when passed in as a parameter.

Many thanks!
Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with something like this?

```
:display_with => lambda { |v| ActiveSupport::Inflector.titleize(v).html_safe }
```

You have to include the complete path because it is not available in the views.

The reason why `@name.titleize` is working is becuase this method in another one that belong to the String class.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize
vs
http://apidock.com/rails/String/titleize

Comment: Just tried it - I get undefined method `titleize' for #<#<Class:0x0000010c8f9c30>:0x00000109f9f0b0> - i.e. same error

Comment: I have updated my answer, I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Can you please explain why the lambda is necessary? I tried it directly, :display_with => ActiveSupport::Inflector.titleize but it didn't work.